# Meteor: Handling events generated from objects wrapped with #each?

Tags: meteor, dynamic, each

So I'm new to meteor, I'm wondering if it's possible to catch an event from a dynamically created element:

```
{{#each appl}}
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading text-center"><b>{{DemUser}}</b></div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <img class="imh-responsive img-rounded col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3" src="/images/faces/face-1.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="panel-footer">
        <div class="row">
          <button class="btn btn-success">Hire</button>
         <button class="btn btn-info">rdv</button>
         <button class="btn btn-danger">Reject</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using an `each`, the context (`this`) in the event map will be an `appl` (applicant?) document. For example:

```js
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'click .btn-success': function () {
    console.log(this._id); // logs appl._id
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks David, It Works, and It's applies, I'm creating a job offres's site